# using react-router and react-router-redux. when i go to localhost:9000/ it works fine, but not localhost:9000/login

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Here's what my router looks like -

```
const router = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Content} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

I updated to do what Elod suggested, however I still get the same issue :(

```
const router = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Content} />
        <Route path="login" component={Footer} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: any error , or just blank page. url changed?

Comment: it just says `Cannot GET /login`

Comment: do you use express?

Comment: how you import history, are you using hashHistory or browserHistory

Comment: i am using browserHistory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115655/discussion-between-utro-and-user1354934).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solution:
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/index.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a parent route of `/` defined.

There's no need to add the `/` at the `Login` component's level. Remove it and leave

`<Route path="login" component={Login} />`

only. Should do the trick for you.

Comment: thanks Elod.  I just tried that, and restarted the server, and still the same issue :(